# In Java, How much memory is allocated on stack and heap for "new Object()"

Tags: java, object, memory, allocation

This was one of my interview question but I am still trying to get my head around it. If I create "new Object()", the reference to this object will be on the stack, which will be 8 bytes on 64 bit. Then, the question was what's on heap. The interviewer later mentioned that two things will always be allocated on heap, which are "Class" object as well as "Monitor". Can someone please explain a bit more about how much memory/what is allocated when "new Object()" gets created?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Ultimately, you executed one/more constructor and ended up with an object data + code, with no reference, hence likely to be GC'd. The function execution allocate "frames" in the stack, while object code and data allocate space on the heap.

Answer (score 6):

Your `new Object()` doesn't have a reference. Its just an object which will be allocated on the heap space.

If it were like:

```
Object someReference = new Object();
```

then `someReference` would be on the *stack* space of *thread*. However the object itself will always be on the heap.

***Lets take an example:***

If you were to execute this statement:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

You'd have memory like:

- **Heap**: stores `new Employee()` i.e. actual object
- **Stack**: stores information about `emp` i.e. reference
- **Perm Space/Metaspace**: stores information about `Employee` class

Comment: Downvoter, please care to leave a comment and atleast suggest how this answer could be improved.

Comment: How much memory is allocated to the object if say my class has some variables, their setters and getters, and a couple of methods?

Answer (score 6):

> If I create "new Object()", the reference to this object will be on the stack, which will be 8 bytes on 64 bit.

Most likely it with be 4 bytes even for a 64-bit JVM. Oracle/OpenJDK support CompressesOops which use 4 bytes for references.

> Then, the question was what's on heap.

The object's header. It has no fields.

> The interviewer later mentioned that two things will always be allocated on heap, which are "Class" object

A `Class` object is a proxy for information stored off heap. It doesn't have to exist even if instances of the class exist (though for Object it probably does already)

> as well as "Monitor".

Again, a monitor is only created if used i.e. `synchornized`

> Can someone please explain a bit more about how much memory/what is allocated when "new Object()" gets created?

On a 64-bit JVM, the header is 12 bytes by default, however with object alignment, it will use 16 bytes. On a 32-bit JVM it will be just 8 bytes.

On a 32-bit JVM and a 64-bit JVM with CompressedOops, a reference is just 4 bytes (which is most JVMs)